# What is the circumference and area of a circle with radius r?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $M$ a Riemann surface with constant Gauss curvature $K = K_{0}$.
Calculate the circumference and area of a circle with radius $r$. Also, calculate the geodesic curvature $K_{g}((r)$ of a circle with radius $r$.

May you please help me answer this questions?Any ideas?

Comment: First note that a "Riemann surface" is not a Riemannian 2-manifold, which you're actually asking.